# Where to find 2.6.1

Tags: ee2, ee2-upgrades

I purchased plugin that requires EE. 2.6.x however I am not prepared to do the changes needed for Safecracker in 2.7.x to upgrade that far.

Where can I find a download for previous versions of Expression Engine - I am a paying customer and cannot find it anywhere on the Ellis labs site. I emailed support but cannot create a "ticket" unless i have a support license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you had a support license, the response from Ellis Labs will be:

- [Unfortunately we do not provide older copies for download](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/212224/#985105)
- [We do not make older versions of EE available](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/158225/#763152)

But there could be light at the end of the tunnel...

[Kevin Cupp to the rescue!](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/236517/)

Comment: Spot on sir - got a reply back with an almost verbatim response.  I appreciate your time.